# How to create a "findByDate" NamedQuery in JPQL?

Tags: java, glassfish, jpql, derby

I'm trying to create a `@NamedQuery` for a web service so that one can return a list of customers that have a given date of birth.

GlassFish reports the following error:

> Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.dob = to_date(:dob, 'dd-Mon-yyyy')]. 
>   [38, 45] The identification variable 'to_date' is not defined in the FROM clause.

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByDob", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.dob = to_date(:dob, 'dd-Mon-yyyy')")

@GET
    @Path("findByDob/{dob}")
    @Produces({"application/json"})
    public List<Customer> findByDob(@PathParam("dob") String dob) {
        Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findByDob");
        q.setParameter("dob", dob);
        return q.getResultList(); 
}
```

Any feedback is much appreciated.

Comment: What kind of database are you using? Seems that function "to_date" not exists in your database product.

Comment: It's apache derby database. Thanks for your feedback, I now understand how to do the named queries when dealing with data types different to String. I would think that derby does support basic functions like to_date but it's not clear to me how to properly access those functions in JPQL and documentation is lacking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delegate the transformation from Date to String database format in the entity manager. Something like this should works:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Customer.findByDob", query = "SELECT c FROM Customer c WHERE c.dob = :dob")

        @GET
        @Path("findByDob/{dob}")
        @Produces({"application/json"})
        public List<Customer> findByDob(@PathParam("dob") String dob) {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-Mon-yyyy");
            Date dobDate = sdf.parse(dob); //Create a new Java Date object. 

            Query q = em.createNamedQuery("Customer.findByDob");
            q.setParameter("dob", dobDate); //The entity manager will transform the Date to query needs.
            return q.getResultList(); 
    }
```